# driver.quit() causes 'Firefox to stop working'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

driver.quit() causes 'Firefox to stop working'

1. The tests do not fail but every time driver.quit is called browser crashes as in the image below.
2. My code:

   ```
   public void quitDriver() throws Exception {
       if (null != webdriver) {
           getDriver().manage().deleteAllCookies();
           webdriver.quit();
           webdriver = null;
       }
   }
   ```

Factory Class:

```
case "firefox":
    if (null == webdriver) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", Constant.GECKO_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
        webdriver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
```

[image]

[image]

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: could you try calling driver.close() before driver.quite() and see if that's helping ?

Comment: @Gaurang Shah thanks for the help, Im afraid it still does the same thing

Comment: what version of `geckodriver` are you using??

Comment: @Saurabh Gaur im using version: v0.14.0

Answer (score 0):

See this [mozilla/geckodriver releases](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) page.

```
v0.14.0

Changed

Firefox process is now terminated and session ended when the last window is closed
WebDriver library updated to version 0.20.0
```

Did you close the last window before calling quit?

Also, geckodriver is still dicey.  Try moving to:

- Webdriver v3.3.1
- geckodriver v0.15.0

Comment: I'm running it with selenium 3.3.1. and gecko 0.15.0 and have the same issue

Comment: @Bgvv1983 Try placing a debugger halt on the quit.  Is the browser window closed?  If so then you don't need the quit.  replace with if (driver != null) {driver.quit();}